# SQL Server subscription error SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I restored a database (db1) which was subscribed to a publisher database. After restoring the db1, I lost the subscription to the publisher, and when I tried to create a new subscription, I get this error:

> Subscription already exist for the database

[image: image of error received]

Answer (score 1):

Well that's one way. Another involves reading the Replication documentation.

Dropping a Subscription:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/delete-a-pull-subscription

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/delete-a-pull-subscription

Bakup and Restore procedures for Repllication:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/administration/strategies-for-backing-up-and-restoring-snapshot-and-transactional-replication

Answer (score 0):

after struggling for a little. restored the db with new name say db2.
then created a subscription for the db2. which worked fine and dropped the db1. later re named the db2 back to db1. this worked for me and i was able to access the publisher again